# Aligning heading tag to the center of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have my HTML Code as follows

```
  <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/starter.jpg" alt="starter">
                <h2> Starter</h2>
            </a>
  </div>
```

below is the CSS i have written and it works fine. but i would like to know what is the best way to position the h2 tag to the center of the image vertically and horizontally. or is this the way to do it?

```
  .portfolio-item h2 {
      left: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 45px;
  }

  .portfolio-item img {
      position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: Could you post an image of your expected outcome? To me it now seems as if you want to center the `h2` tag on top of the image, is this correct?

Comment: Absolutely. i want the heading to be on top of the image and aligned at the center vertically and horizontally. what i have done is working fine. but i feel this is not the correct way @timo

Comment: then I think my answer will suit your needs =).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the answer is updated from the comments:

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.portfolio-item a {position: relative; display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
.portfolio-item a img, .portfolio-item a span {position: absolute; left: 0;}
.portfolio-item a span {top: 50%; margin-top: -0.75em; width: 100px; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
  <h2>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="starter" />
      <span>Starter</span>
    </a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Note the comments to question. The heading is supposed to be **on top** of the image...not next to it.

Comment: @praveen. Heading is suppose to be on top of the image and problem with my CSS is when the letter in the heading increases, it doesn't look like its align to the center.

Comment: Oh Okay. I got the logic now. You need to have `position: absolute`.

Comment: @Shareer1 Check out now!

Answer (score 1):

Use the link as the containing element and then position the heading accordingly

```css
* {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-item a {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.portfolio-item a h2 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  background:lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="starter" />
    <h2> Starter</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the h2 inside a span that covers the complete 100% of the parent. 
I gave this a display table-cell.

The `:before` class makes sure the parent is actualy stretched 100% so you can center it vertically.

```
<div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.blackfeathers.nl/Testbeeld.jpg" alt="starter">
        <span>
            <h2> Starter</h2>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    }
span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
span:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ycn9cxys/3/)